# Direct sum of Hilbert/Sobolev Space?

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, sobolev-spaces, direct-sum

Our professor the other day wrote the following on the blackboard: "Let $u(x)=(v(x),w(x))$ be such that $u \in H^{2,1}$ where $H^{2,1}=H^2 \oplus H^1$." He then mumbled something about this space which I failed to hear. Due to silly me, getting embarassed to ask questions in front of an audience, I didn't raise my hand. So here I am, asking:

Is this the direct sum of the Hilbert spaces $H^k=W^{k,2}$? What is the respective norm, i.e how do I interpret $\| u\|_{H^{2,1}}$?

Many thanks in advance for any help and merry Christmas!

Comment: Unless you had more context, I would interpret $H^1,H^2$ as just being arbitrary $\Bbbk$-Hilbert spaces (with $\Bbbk$ being other $\mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{C}$), and then $H^{2,1}=H^2\oplus H^1$ as their direct sum, i.e. $H^{2,1}=H^2\times H^2$ as a set, and the inner product is given by $\langle (u_1,v_1),(u_2,v_2)\rangle_{H^{2,1}}=\langle u_1,u_2\rangle_{H^2}+\langle v_1,v_2\rangle_{H^1}$.

Comment: @Lorago many thanks for the comment. Well, $u$ denotes the solution of a reaction-diffusion system. Do you think I should include it in my post?

Comment: I guess $v$ should be in $H^2$ and $w$ in $H^1$. Does this fit with the system?

Comment: @JonasLenz hmmm...yeah, that could be a fit!